# Word problem in the braid group

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory, braid-groups

The geodesic length of elements can be defined as the length of a minimal path from 1 to w in the Cayley graph of G. This length is dependent on the particular generating set X.

The Word Problem is decidable in G if and only if the geodesic length function is computable.

Sufficiency is obvious, but why is the necessity needed? Further, "computable" I interpret as the calculation terminates in a finite number of steps, with the correct answer, is this correct, or is it more nuanced?

The braid group has a quadratic Dehn function, i.e., there exist constants $C_n$, $C'_n$ such that, if w is an n-strand braid word of length $l$ that represents the unit braid, then the number of braid relations needed to transform $w$ into the empty word is at most $C_n l^{2}$ and, on the other hand, there exists for each $l$ at least one length $l$ word $w$ such that the minimal number of such braid relations is at least $C'_n l^2$. [This paragraph is copied from Combinatorial Distance between Braid Words, P. Dehornoy, which mentions it is a well-known result]

Because the first result is if and only if, this, together with the braid group having a quadratic Dehn function, (presumably) means that word problem in the braid group is decidable. Does this mean that the Dehn function can be used to calculate the geodesic length in the braid group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, computable means that there is an algorithm to solve the problem that is guaranteed  to succeed on all inputs.

If the word problem in  $G$ is solvable, then you can compute the geodesic length of $g \in G$ as follows.

For $n := 0, 1,2,3 \ldots$, write down all words of length $n$ and check whether any of them are equal in $G$ to $g$. When you find such an element, stop: the geodesic length of $g$ is $n$.

Comment: With this increasing length enumeration being “efficient” because the word problem is defined in terms of groups with finite generators. Although the sequence produced by Dehn’s algorithm will terminate to the identity for identity words, for non-identity words is the final term (which is necessarily a non-identity) geodesic?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your question. What I wrote down is an algorithm to solve the problem that you asked, and it does that. It outputs the geodesic length  $n$ of the given element $g$, together with a specific word of length $n$ that evaluates to $g$. I  didn't say anything about efficiency of the solution. Also I didn't say anything about Dehn's algorithm. All I am assuming is that the word problem of the group is solvable, I am not assuming anything about the method of solving it, which can be regarded as a black box.

Comment: The answer / solution you provided is very helpful and understandable. My comment could have been worded better (please ignore the efficiency comment!). In your answer, Dehn’s algorithm could be used to see if two words are equal by multiplying one by the inverse of the other and seeing if this is the identity? But just calculating Dehn’s algorithm on a word of interest (and not using the method in your answer) will not give the geodesic value unless the word is the identity?

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of Dehn's algorithm. Dehn's algorithm can only be used to solve the word problem in hyperbolic groups, and braid groups are not hyperbolic. But you are right, in hyperbolic groups, Dehn's algorithm cannot in general be used to reduce a word to a geodesic word - in fact that is only possible in virtually free groups. But there is a quadratic time algorithm for the geodesic problem in hyperbolic groups. I doubt whether there is a subexponential time method of solving your problem in braid groups (but I might be wrong).

Comment: This helps immensely. Understood. I was mistaken that Dehn’s algorithm was applicable to Braid groups.